# Using property placeholder location

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, property-placeholder

I have **database.properties** file with some properties defined.
And also **application-context.xml** file where I'm trying to put these values to ***databaseRepository*** bean properties:

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:property_placeholder/database.properties"/>
<bean id="databaseRepository" class="property_placeholder.DatabaseRepository">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

but when I'm trying to run app and read **database.properties** file I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: property_placeholder\database.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at property_placeholder.MainSpring.main(MainSpring.java:9)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: property_placeholder\database.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:168)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
... 12 more
```

Here's how files structure looks like:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACSYK.png)

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I suggest trying `classpath:` instead of `file:`, since your file seems to be in the classpath and not outside in a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually `FileNotFoundException: property_placeholder\database.properties`, so makes sure that you provide the correct path to your properties file.

Here a correct path could be `classpath:property_placeholder/database.properties` according to your structure.

You need to put your file `database.properties` under `resources/property_placeholder`

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful but I also had to copy the database.properties file to the proper target subfolder.

Answer (score 4):

use this config in your application context file  : put your properties file in resources .

```
<bean
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
<value>classpath:database.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. When I moved property file to resources folder, I didn't need to copy it manually to proper target subfolder.